# Restoring Hyperledger Fabric Network After It Is Off

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am working on a project using hyperledger fabric.

Currently, I use the test-network in the hyperledger fabric document to develop it fabric document.

But what I'm worried about is if my computer turns off and the hyperledger fabric network turns off, will I be able to restore the previous network values again?

What should I do if I can?

In the current practice example, if you enter the test-network ./network.sh down command, you can see that the generated msp(?) files and authentication-related files. Should I modify this network.sh file so that the generated authentication-related files are not deleted when the server goes down, and if the file exists when the server is turned on again, should I modify it so that the network can be configured?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retain your current network, even in a stopped state, run the following command in the docker folder.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-couch.yaml -f docker-compose-ca.yaml -f docker-compose-test-net.yaml  stop
```

This command stops the current containers from running. When you want to start the same network again, use the same command and use start instead of stop, as shown next.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-couch.yaml -f docker-compose-ca.yaml -f docker-compose-test-net.yaml  start
```

Using `./network down` command removes all traces of the network, other than the files that were there from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

> But what I'm worried about is if my computer turns off and the hyperledger fabric network turns off, will I be able to restore the previous network values again?

If the containers are in Exited(not due to errors) state you can bring those containers Up again.
Normally we maintain persistence DB to store data.

In Test network we are not bothered about restarting the network and generating new certs repeatedly. If it is a prod env we just execute the script(network.js) only once.

You can also make changes(micro-scripts) to the existing scripts based on your use-case/requirements.